# What are the best methods to measure velocity given

Tags: math

Given that you have thousands of 3D vectors with their time of insertion, and you want to find the instantaneous velocity at the current time? Also, the primary criterion is accuracy, with the secondary criterion being performance.

Sample data:

t is in milliseconds (low resolution)

> ```
> :> t: 19624, x: -221.68, y: 394.46, z: 127.66
> :> t: 19656, x: -222.07, y: 394.26, z: 127.54
> :> t: 19671, x: -222.47, y: 394.06, z: 127.43
> :> t: 19687, x: -222.53, y: 394.03, z: 127.36
> :> t: 19718, x: -222.95, y: 393.81, z: 127.23
> :> t: 19734, x: -222.95, y: 393.81, z: 127.23
> :> t: 19749, x: -223.42, y: 393.58, z: 127.05
> :> t: 19765, x: -223.42, y: 393.58, z: 127.05
> :> t: 19796, x: -223.86, y: 393.36, z: 126.91
> :> t: 19812, x: -224.30, y: 393.13, z: 126.77
> :> t: 19827, x: -224.36, y: 393.11, z: 126.71
> :> t: 19843, x: -224.36, y: 393.11, z: 126.71
> :> t: 19858, x: -224.82, y: 392.87, z: 126.55
> :> t: 19874, x: -225.27, y: 392.65, z: 126.48
> :> t: 19890, x: -225.32, y: 392.63, z: 126.49 [current time]
> ```

Comment: It's not... I want to find a better way to approximate velocity for a game than my current solution.

Comment: This question isn't clear to me. You have thousands of 3D vectors of what? Vectors can represent position, velocity, or any number of things. I'm guessing that you meant position. By time of insertion, do you mean that you basically have x(t) with various times, t, and x being the 3D position/velocity/other vectors?

Comment: Yes, position. I edited the first post with example data so it's more clear.

Comment: The average velocity between two points in time `t_i` and `t_j` is just (x_t_j - x_t_i, y_t_j - y_t_i, z_t_j - z_t_i).  You can't *really* get the instantaneous velocity at t_j because you don't have a function describing position (which you could differentiate or sample at very small intervals) or a function describing velocity (which you could evaluate directly).  What is your current approach and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Linear extrapolation over a section of time, and then using that extrapolated data to get the instantaneous velocity. However, linear extrapolation isn't so reliable. Approximation of course.

Comment: @user239201, Extrapolation?  Do you mean interpolation?  The method of finding the average velocity between points is not necessarily accurate at any given instant, but it is accurate overall:  if you integrate, you will recover the positions.  If you describe your *problem* better it will be easier to see what you're looking for.  P.s. I forgot to divide by the difference in time above.

Comment: No, I mean extrapolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation#Linear_extrapolation The problem is, I would like to extrapolate from less data without having the results being too unreliable. I know there are other extrapolation techniques, but I'm not so familiar with them, and many are too slow (maybe someone knows of good approximations). The reason I want to extrapolate from less data, is because then the results become more responsive.

Comment: I don't really get it: Why do you have !thousands! of positions if what you want is the current velocity (to extrapolate the next position I suppose). And how are the positions calculated (Don't you have the velocity at your disposal?. And: Why not?)? I'd very much appreciate if you set a context for your problem, like: multiplayer, high latency, moving objects, guessing their next position foo/whatever.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating over the vector of velocities to calculate acceleration and use this in conjunction with the last velocity?

Answer (score 0):

velocity with respect to `OX`, `OY` and `OZ` axes is the second derivative of `x(t)`, `y(t)` and `z(t)`.

The first defivative (suppose `t=1`) if easy to find

```
x'(1) = x(1) - x(0)
```

and

```
x''(2) = x'(2) - x'(1)
```

it will be fast enough but it wount be accurate. So I recoment you to approximate the series of x(t) with continious function (polynom), and calculate the second derivative of that polynom. Try to read about interpolation polynomes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).